# A few questions

Tags: geometry

These are sample questions that I wasn't able to solve.

[image]

The length of a tangent drawn from a point $8cm$ away from the center of circle of radius $6cm$ is

If perimeter of a protractor is $72cm$. Calculate its area

These $3$ questions I wasn't able to solve in this question paper, help is much appreciated!

Comment: At least the first part seems to be incomplete...

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- For the three circles: calculate the side of the triangle, the radii of the circles, the areas of the sectors and then subtract
- For the incomplete tangent and centre question: can you spot a right-angled triangle?
- For the protractor: express the perimeter as a function of the radius, calculate the radius, and then calculate the area

Answer (score 0):

For question $\,34\,$ : if the triangle's side is $\,a\,$ , then

$$17,320.5=S_\Delta=\frac{\sqrt 3 a^2}{4}\Longrightarrow a= 200$$

The area of each of the three sectors is

$$A=\frac{\pi}{3}\frac{a^2}{4}\ldots$$